every neighborhood of every zero of Brownian motion takes positive and negative values almost surely
How can I prove that almost surely every neighborhood of every zero of Brownian motion takes positive and negative values? (*)
I can already prove that for every zero of Brownian motion, Brownian motion takes positive and negative values on every neighborhood of that  zero almost surely. (**)
That is I can prove it for every single zero but that set of measure one for different zeros can be different. If set of all zeros of Brownian motion were countable then I would be done because intersection of countably many events with probability one is an event of probability one, but it is uncountable.
My book says that in order to prove (*) one can use fact that set of zeros of Brownian motion is closed set with no isolated points (^), but I don't see how to use this fact.
I can prove (**) using different method than the fact (^).

I am pretty sure this is a consequence of Blumenthal's 0-1 law, if you are familiar with it.

@confusedTurtle That's the entire point of the question and I am sure the op is familiar with it. With Blumenthal's 0-1 law (coupled with Strong Markov Property), you can conclude the property for a fixed zero. But that is not enough to conclude for all zeroes as you cannot take an uncountable intersection of all the probability $1$ sets.

@confusedTurtle i.e. if you are given that $z$ is a unique(almost surely) zero of a Brownian Motion. For example, the first time the brownian motion is zero after time $1$, then, as it's an almost surely finite stopping time, you can use the Blumenthal Zero-One law and the Strong Markov Property at that stopping time to conclude that almost surely for all Brownian sample paths, the Brownian motion will take positive and negative values in any neighbourhood of that zero. The question asks to prove that almost surely for all sample paths, and for all zeroes(uncountably many), the property holds.

You can imitate the proof for the fact that the zero set is closed and has no isolated points. You can restrict to a countable set of zeroes which will be dense in the set of zeroes. For example if $z_{q}=\inf\{t\geq q:B_{t}=0\}$, $q\in\Bbb{Q}$.
Then, for a fixed $q$, you can apply Blumenthal's zero-one law and Strong Markov Property to have that $(B_{z_{q}+t})_{t\geq 0}$ is a Brownian Motion independent of the past and it takes both positive and negative values in any neighbourhood of $z_{q}$ almost surely.
That is, you'll get a set $A_{q}$ of probability $1$ such that for all sample paths in it, the Brownian motion will take both positive and negative values in any neighbourhood of $z_{q}$.
Now, you can take the intersection over $q$ to get a single set $A$ of probability $1$ for which each $z_{q}$ satisfies the desired property.

(A small technical point which can be safely ignored is that the
stopping time $z_{q}$ is only almost surely finite. So, you'll also need to
intersect $A_{q}$ with $B_{q}$ which is a set of probability $1$ for
which the stopping time $z_{q}$ is finite for all sample paths. This
does not affect the proof as again, you'll end up with a set
$A\cap B=\bigcap_{q\in\Bbb{Q}}A_{q}\cap B_{q}$ of probability $1$)

Now, let $z\in Z$ be an arbitrary zero in the random set $Z$ which is different from a $z_{q}$.

(If $z=z_{q}$, then there is nothing more to prove and we are done)

Inside an $\epsilon$ ball $B(z,\epsilon)$ around $z$, you can find a sequence of rationals $q_{n}$'s such that $q_{n}\uparrow z$ and $z-\epsilon<q_{n}<z$ for all $n$.
And, you also have that $q_{n}\leq z_{q_{n}}< z$ by definition of the stopping time .

(The strict inequality is due to the assumption that $z$ is not of the
form $z_{q}$.)

Thus, choose any such $z_{q_{n}}$ close enough to $z$ such that  $B(z,\epsilon)$ forms an open neighbourhood of $z_{q_{n}}$ and then inside $B(z,\epsilon)$, you'll have that the Brownian Motion takes both positive and negative values by what we have already shown for zeroes of the form $z_{q}$ and their neighbourhoods.

It suffices to show the property for $\epsilon$ ball neighbourhoods
instead of general open neighbourhoods as the balls form a basis for
the Euclidean topology.

This holds true for all sample paths which lie in $A$ which is a set of probability $1$ and hence the proof is complete.
